# How to debug ISAPI using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, isapi

as title, my friend's environment is Windows 2003 server. He attached the IIS process and set the breaking points at codes supposed to run, but VS doesn't stop at all. The ISAPI is written with VC++.

Is there any setting he need to set up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual studio can debug various types of Code:  Native, Script, Managed, Silverlight etc.  You need to ensure that when you attach that the Attach To: box contains "Native code".

You also need to be sure you are attaching to the correct instance of w3wp.exe if there is more than one.

Comment: @PuspenduBanerjee:  You built the extension in the Debug configuration?  You referenced the dll for the location to which VS built it?  You are attaching the correct instance of w3wp.exe (there may be more than one)?  You are ensuring that you have "Native" selected as the type of code to debug?

Comment: Everything I did, except I have copied the dll under my application folder [wwwroot]

Comment: @PuspenduBanerjee: Then thats your problem, to debug you need VS's understanding of path relationships (between compiled component and source code) to be maintained which means you need keep the dll in the original place that VS wrote it to.

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of late, but there is an easier way.

- Right click your (ISAPI) project, select Properties
- In the dialog select Configuration Properties->Debug
- Enter:

  - Command : C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
  - Command Arguments : -debug
- Now do "Start Debugging(F5)" for you project.

Visual Studio will launch a test instance of IIS and you can debug your DLL, no need to attach to process, etc.

Make sure to stop IIS service beforehand.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with IIS 8.5. However, I found that Visual Studio must be run as administrator for IIS to load the ISAPI extension.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend is debugging a site on his localhost, AnthonyWJones' advice should suffice.

If its a different machine he may need to run the Visual Studio Remote Debugger and give himself permission to attach to the process.

You can use a tool like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to help you figure out which process has your extension/filter loaded so you can attach to the right one.