# How to debug an ISAPI Filter?

Tags: isapi

ISAPI Filters are dll's that get attached to the w3wp process of IIS web server. ISAPI Filters have to compulsorily export two functions viz. HttpFilterProc and GetFilterVersion. I have written one such filter but it is not working in the way that the switch case in HttpFilterProc is not getting activated. What can i do to check whats wrong here ?

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470314/how-to-debug-isapi-using-visual-studio/10037270

Answer (score 2):

Add a call to DebugBreak in your HttpFilterProc and build your DLL in debug mode before adding it as ISAPI filter.

If your HttpFilterProc gets called, windows would popup a message to debug the process.

If it doesn't your DLL is not getting loaded. You need to check why it is not. Some reasons may be:

1. The ISAPI filter is configured with different bitness as compared to the application pool bitness.
2. You have not registered for any ISAPI events in your GetFilterVersion function. See list of ISAPI events [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525822(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Approach with `DebugBreak` command injection works, but why I it doesn't work when I attach to w3wp.exe running my website? It attaches OK, but it doesn't load ISAPI filter symbols ("The breakpoints will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document")?

Comment: @MikeKeskinov You sure the correct libraries were used while running the website? This generally happens when there is a mismatch between the code base and the loaded DLLs inside the executable while attaching.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, because I have one project open. When I put `DebugBreak` in it, build it, attach to IIS, then I can debug it when it hits `DebugBreak`. If I simple build it without DebugBreak, I try to attach to process w3wp for the running website, it doesn't load by breakpoints in ISAPI filter which is used by the website. May be ISAPI run by some different process?